# QAbstractItemView selectAll slow

Tags: c++, qt, qtableview, qabstractitemview

I have a `QTableView` with around 10k entries. When I call `QAbstractItemView::selectAll` it takes about 5secs to complete. The performance otherwise is OK.

1. Why is the selection so slow?
2. and is there something I can do to speed it up?

Comment: I think it is something that has to do with your model, I've just ran [this](http://pastebin.com/8TzhyYin) on Qt 5.6.1, and `selectAll()` took 1 milli second here.

Comment: Is there a difference if you already have any items selected or not?

Comment: Try running your test inside a profiler (if you're on a Mac, Apple's "Instruments" program works very well, or Activity Monitor's "Sample Process" feature will do in a pinch).  That will show you where your program is spending its time during those 5 seconds.

Comment: @Mike I also think it is model related, only I do not see how. I wonder what the relation is. Have to check if `data()` or something else is called for all items. 
@Jon No obvious difference if items are already selected

Guess I really have to use a profiler

Comment: 1) Always profile. 2) I was curious if a hunch about `QItemSelection` would bear out.